# How to merge two (or more) rows using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge two rows in Excel using VBA in order to create a new row with the combination values of selected rows using a factor x.

```
alpha 5 6 8 3 ...
beta 10 1 5 7 ...
```

With alpha and beta I want to create row ab70 (x=.7)

```
ab70 6.5 4.5 7.1 4.2 ...
(5*.7+10(1-.7)) ...
```

I would like to create this from a GUI in VBA selecting from a list the materials and chosing the factor x.

Thanks :D
L

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you're having ?  What is stopping you from reaching your goal?

Comment: Well, I am knew with VBA. I tought that knowing Excel was just fine until I started in january working with VBA. I am using this for a project and this is were I got stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) Is `(5*.7+10(1-.7))` an explanation for `6.5` or is it required output? (2) Has .7 been entered by the user? (3) Where have `ab70` come from? (4) What list of materials? (5) If `alpha 5 ...` and `beta 10 1 ...` are input where is the output to go? (6) How far have you got with your solution? (Summary) I do not believe anyone could get you started with such a vague specification.

Comment: Let's say that its a 50 item list of materials. Then, user choses name of mix of materials (ab70) and x (from 0 to 1). This x will represent the percentage of a material in the new mix. Then, if x=.7, ab70 is material a (column b)*.7+material b(column b)*(1-.7). Let's assume there are 50 columns as well.

Comment: I have already done the exercise in Excel but I fail to code it via VBA. So far, I have done progress in my project by using the Macro recorder. However, for this particular situation I believe a GUI is required. I tought of a simple interface asking for the name of new material, two combo boxes with the list of materials and x as input.

Answer (score 0):

The first version of this answer was more concerned with clarifying the requirement than answering the question.  The second version is closer to an proper answer.  Questions in the first version which were answered in comments have been deleted.

**First version after removal of questions**

This is not a site which can teach you to create a userform although you could get help with the code for a control.  Try searching the web for “excel vba userform tutorial”.  There are a number to choose from.  I have not tried any so cannot make a recommendation.

A List box allows the program to provide a list from which the user can select one or more items.  A Combo box allows the program to provide a list from which the user can select one item or enter a new value that is not within the list.  You do not want the user to be able to specify their own material so you need a List Box.  By default the user can only select one item which is what you want.

**Second version**

This will not be a complete answer.  I will give you design ideas which you can then develop to meet your exact requirement or you can clarify your requirement and I will develop them a little more.  I will give you some useful code but not all you will need for the complete solution.

You say that combining two materials would meet your immediate needs but in the longer term you wish to combine more.  There are different approaches to addressing such a situation:

1. Design and implement a solution for the immediate need now.  Redesign for the longer term later.
2. Design and implement a solution for the long term need now.
3. Design a solution for the long term then implement as much of the long-term design as seems appropriate.

None of these approaches will be correct in every case.  If you are working to a deadline, approach 1 many be the only choice.  Approach 1 may also be appropriate if you lack experience with the technology and wish for a simple implementation as a training exercise.  When I was young, distributing a new version of an application to multiple users could be very expensive and approach 2 would often be the preferred approach.  These days, approach 3 is normally my preference.

From your comments I deduce you are thinking of something like:

[image: Possible user form for immediate need]

The two list boxes are filled with the names of the materials so the user can click one row in the first list box and one in the second to specify the two materials.  Text boxes allow the user to enter the Proportion and the Name.  I have used the blue “Rem” to represent the remainder (1 – x) which you may wish to display as a comment.  You may not have thought of buttons.  There should always be an Exit button in case the user has started the macro unintentionally.  Clicking a button to save the mixture allows the user to check the four values first.

I think this could be an excellent design for the two material version.  If we ignore the actual merging of the rows, there would be little code behind this form.

I do not know how long your material names are but I assume this design could be expanded for three or four materials by adding extra list boxes to the right with a Proportion text box under all but the last list.  However, this arrangement would have a low maximum number of materials in a mixture.  This will be acceptable if you do have a low maximum.  You might also allow the user to mix mixtures thereby allowing an unlimited number of base materials in a mixture.

The code behind a form that allowed three or four materials in a mixture would be only a little more complicated than that behind the two material version.

I have two alternative designs that would perhaps be better with a higher maximum number of materials but it will not outline then unless you indicates that this first design is unacceptable.

I would expect any good tutorial to explain the various methods of loading a list box with values to I will not repeat them.

---

However you decide to handle the selection of materials and their proportions, you will need a routine to generate the new row.

I have created a worksheet “Material” and have set the first few rows and columns so:

[image: Example data]

I appreciate you have many more rows and columns but my data is adequate for a test and demonstration.  Note in the heading line "Prop" is short for "Property".

You need to tell the routine which merges rows, which rows to mix. The user will select material B2 say.  You could pass “B2” to the routine and let it discover the row from which it had come but this would make the routine more difficult to code than necessary.  When loading the list boxes from this worksheet, values will be taken from column A of rows 2 to 12.    I would expect your user form tutorial to explain that your code can identify the value selected by the user either by value (B2) or by index (4th row).  You know the 1st row of the list box was loaded from row 2 of the worksheet so you can calculate that the 4th row of the list box was loaded from row 5 of the worksheet.

You need to tells the routine the proportions entered by the user and the name of the mixture.

Above I listed three possible approaches to deciding how much to implement.  An addition to any of these approaches is the inclusion of flexibility that is not required but is as easy or is easier to include than exclude.

The declaration for my routine is:

```
Sub RecordNewMixture(ByVal WshtName, ByRef RowSrc() As Long, ByRef Prop() As Single, _
                     ByVal MaterialNameNew As String)
```

You will only have one worksheet holding materials and its name is unlikely to change so I could hardcode that worksheet’s name into the routine.  However, it almost as easy to make the worksheet name a parameter and I think it makes the code tidier so I have make it a parameter.

The routine requires the array Prop() hold all the proportions including the last.  So, for example, (0.7, 0.3) or (0.3, 0.3, 0.4).  The user form will have to calculate the last proportion so it might as well pass the last proportion.  I have made Prop() an array of Singles which I assume will give you adequate precision.  If you do not understand the last sentence I can explain.  Note that here "Prop" is short for proportion.  Sorry for using "Prop" as an abbreviation for both "Property" and "Proportion".  I did not notice until I the final checking of this text.

I needed a routine to test `Sub RecordNewMixture` so I have provided it as a demonstration.  Note that I have coded and tested this routine without any involvement of the user form.  It is always a good idea to develop and test your routines in isolation before combining them into the finished product.

After running the macro, worksheet “Material” has two new rows:

[image: Sample data after running macro]

If you duplicate the new rows with formulae, you will find that the values are as you require.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Dim RowSrc() As Long
  Dim Prop() As Single

  ReDim RowSrc(0 To 1)
  ReDim Prop(0 To 1)

  RowSrc(0) = 2:   Prop(0) = 0.7!
  RowSrc(1) = 4:   Prop(1) = 0.3!

  Call RecordNewMixture("Material", RowSrc, Prop, "Join24")

  ReDim RowSrc(1 To 3)
  ReDim Prop(1 To 3)

  RowSrc(1) = 3:   Prop(1) = 0.3!
  RowSrc(2) = 6:   Prop(2) = 0.3!
  RowSrc(3) = 9:   Prop(3) = 0.4!

  Call RecordNewMixture("Material", RowSrc, Prop, "Join369")

End Sub
Sub RecordNewMixture(ByVal WshtName, ByRef RowSrc() As Long, ByRef Prop() As Single, _
                     ByVal MaterialNameNew As String)

  ' * RowSrc is an array containing the numbers of the rows in worksheet WshtName
  '   that are to be mixed to create a new material.
  ' * Prop is an array containing the proportions of each source material in the new
  '   mixture.
  ' * Arrays RowSrc and Prop must have the same lower and upper bounds.
  ' * MaterialNameNew is the name of the mixture.
  ' * Each data row in Worksheet WshtName defines a material. Column A contains the
  '   name of the material. The remaining columns contain numeric properties of the
  '   material.
  '   Each data row in Worksheet WshtName must have the same maximum number of
  '   columns. Call this value ColLast.
  ' * This routine creates a new row below any existing rows within worksheet
  '   WshtName.  Call this row RowNew. The values in this new row are:
  '    * Column A = MaterialNameNew
  '    * For ColCrnt = 2 to ColMax
  '    *   Cell(RowNew, ColCrnt) = Sum of Cell(RowSrc(N), ColCrnt) * Prop(N)
  '                                for N = LBound(RowSrc) to UBound(RowSrc)

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim InxRowSrc As Long
  Dim RowNew As Long
  Dim ValueNewCrnt As Single

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Worksheets(WshtName)

    ' Locate the row before the last row with a value in column A
    RowNew = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Store name of new material
    .Cells(RowNew, "A") = MaterialNameNew

    ' Locate the last column in the first source row.  Assume same
    ' last column for all other source rows
    ColLast = .Cells(RowSrc(LBound(RowSrc)), Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For ColCrnt = 2 To ColLast
      ' If Single does not give adequate precision, change the declaration of
      ' Prop() and ValueNewCrnt to Double. If you do this, replace "0!" by "0#"
      ValueNewCrnt = 0!
      For InxRowSrc = LBound(RowSrc) To UBound(RowSrc)
        ValueNewCrnt = ValueNewCrnt + .Cells(RowSrc(InxRowSrc), ColCrnt).Value * Prop(InxRowSrc)
      Next
      .Cells(RowNew, ColCrnt) = ValueNewCrnt
    Next

  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I appreciate your comments. You are right, I need help with the code. The logic behind it for the buttons and the selection I'll do it on the user form. What I need help the most with is to select the row of the specific material and to multiply it for the other selected row. How do I do that? I mean, the combo box will select a material from a list, then, how do I tell VBA to save this line? Thanks :D

Comment: Until you have a clear specification, you should not think about the code.  The maximum number of rows that can be selected will significantly affect the design,  Is my description of your data correct?  If not please provide your own description. Where are the new rows to be placed?  Can the user specify multiple mixed rows per call of the user form?  These are the questions that come to mind at the moment.  Once those are answered I will probably have more.

Comment: Tony, your description is right. It is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Actually, for the time being, I only need to combine two rows so x and (1-x) will do the job. However, I like to think ahead and tought of different scenarios (3 or more rows). For the new rows I thought of placing them right below the last item of column A. The user will only specify a mix of the original list of materials (20) not from the mix of the new ones. Thanks again!

Comment: Tony, as time is a constraint, I will stick with approach number 1. I have tested your code with a demo UI and it works :D I appreciate your help!